# NuGet problems after moving my Visual Studio extension from old csproj to SDK-style csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I've switched my Visual Studio extension from old csproj format to the new SDK-style format and hoped to get everything I need with the following package references (previously I had to reference like 100 different packages in my packages.config)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices" Version="3.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK" Version="16.0.206" />
<PackageReference Include="NuGet.VisualStudio" Version="5.8.0" />
```

However, while the extension builds within Visual Studio, I run into problems when building the extension with MSBuild (when restoring NuGet packages):

```
"C:\Path\MyExt\MyExtension.sln" (Build target) (1) ->
   "C:\Path\MyExt\MyExt.Tests\MyExt.Tests.csproj" (default target) (9) ->
     C:\Path\MyExt\MyExt.Tests\MyExt.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text 3.8.0 depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility (>= 16.8.39) but Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility 16.8.39 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility 16.8.239 was resolved.
     C:\Path\MyExt\MyExt.Tests\MyExt.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text 3.8.0 depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility (>= 16.8.39) but Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility 16.8.39 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility 16.8.239 was resolved.
     C:\Path\MyExt\MyExt.Tests\MyExt.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text 3.8.0 depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data (>= 16.8.39) but Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data 16.8.39 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data 16.8.239 was resolved.
     C:\Path\MyExt\MyExt.Tests\MyExt.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text 3.8.0 depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data (>= 16.8.39) but Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data 16.8.39 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data 16.8.239 was resolved.
     C:\Path\MyExt\MyExt.Tests\MyExt.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text 3.8.0 depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic (>= 16.8.39) but Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic 16.8.39 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic 16.8.239 was resolved.
     C:\Path\MyExt\MyExt.Tests\MyExt.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text 3.8.0 depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic (>= 16.8.39) but Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic 16.8.39 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic 16.8.239 was resolved.
```

Indeed, the packages are not on NuGet. Is this a problem with the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK` package? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi D.R, any update about this issue?

Comment: I will have the time on Friday to go through your reply - thanks in advance for taking the time! I will report back soon!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That is your choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is related the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures` package itself. And you should contact with the author.

It's just that the problem is magnified by the new-sdk project and the true you set.

[image]

**Actually**, I faced the same issue in my side with even net core console project.

You can see this:

The nuget package has dependencies are  >=`16.8.39`.

[image]

**However**, `Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility` does not have version `16.8.39` version but has `16.8.239`. This is designed by the author. And according to the mechanism of nuget, it will install the minimum version of dependencies, but **the new-sdk style project** cannot automatically identify the invalid version, and this warning appears. But non-sdk style projects with `packages.config` will automatically install the valid version of the nuget dependencies.

**So** this issue is the dual influence of the design issue of the nuget package and the particularity of the new-sdk style project. It's just magnified in this case.

[image]

============================================

**Workaround**

To solve the issue, try these:

**1) First**, disable `TreatWarningsAsErrors` node under **Project Properties**-->**Build**

[image]

**2)** manually install

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility 16.8.239

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data 16.8.239

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic 16.8.239
```

nuget packages additionally to update the dependencies.

**3)** then enable `TreatWarningsAsErrors` to check.

Comment: Thanks for your time & elaborate reply. Installing those three packages manually triggered many more similar errors. I've created the following GitHub issue at Roslyn, maybe they can fix the situation: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49787

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and maybe you could share the errors if possible.

Comment: I've fixed them by pinpointing lots of packages now, very unclean, but it seems to be the way to go until they fix the packages. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/49787#discussioncomment-194129 for the solution.